# Changing the background of a div based on the results of a quiz

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web, radio-button

Alright, I'm stuck here a little bit. For work, I had to create a quiz, and bases off of the results (the highest number of As, Bs, Cs, Ds, or Es) they'd like the background color of a corresponding div to change color slightly. I've done some searching around with little luck, but here's what I have so far (it's all in one file because the content manager we use doesn't let us link correctly.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var winner = 0;

    function checkTest() {
        var Acount = 0;
        var Bcount = 0;
        var Ccount = 0;
        var Dcount = 0;
        var Ecount = 0;

        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=amReach]:checked').val() == "Q1A") { Acount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=amReach]:checked').val() == "Q1B") { Bcount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=amReach]:checked').val() == "Q1C") { Ccount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=amReach]:checked').val() == "Q1D") { Dcount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=amReach]:checked').val() == "Q1E") { Ecount++; }

        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=transportation]:checked').val() == "Q2A") { Acount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=transportation]:checked').val() == "Q2B") { Bcount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=transportation]:checked').val() == "Q2C") { Ccount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=transportation]:checked').val() == "Q2D") { Dount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=transportation]:checked').val() == "Q2E") { Ecount++; }

        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=SocialNetwork]:checked').val() == "Q3A") { Acount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=SocialNetwork]:checked').val() == "Q3B") { Bcount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=SocialNetwork]:checked').val() == "Q3C") { Ccount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=SocialNetwork]:checked').val() == "Q3D") { Dcount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=SocialNetwork]:checked').val() == "Q3E") { Ecount++; }

        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=FridayNight]:checked').val() == "Q4A") { Acount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=FridayNight]:checked').val() == "Q4B") { Bcount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=FridayNight]:checked').val() == "Q4C") { Ccount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=FridayNight]:checked').val() == "Q4D") { Dcount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=FridayNight]:checked').val() == "Q4E") { Ecount++; }

        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=HIMYM]:checked').val() == "Q5A") { Acount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=HIMYM]:checked').val() == "Q5B") { Bcount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=HIMYM]:checked').val() == "Q5C") { Ccount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=HIMYM]:checked').val() == "Q5D") { Dcount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=HIMYM]:checked').val() == "Q5E") { Ecount++; }

        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=MileyCyrus]:checked').val() == "Q6A") { Acount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=MileyCyrus]:checked').val() == "Q6B") { Bcount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=MileyCyrus]:checked').val() == "Q6C") { Ccount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=MileyCyrus]:checked').val() == "Q6D") { Dcount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=MileyCyrus]:checked').val() == "Q6E") { Ecount++; }

        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=WeatherForecaster]:checked').val() == "Q7A") { Acount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=WeatherForecaster]:checked').val() == "Q7B") { Bcount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=WeatherForecaster]:checked').val() == "Q7C") { Ccount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=WeatherForecaster]:checked').val() == "Q7D") { Dcount++; }
        if ($('input[type="radio"][name=WeatherForecaster]:checked').val() == "Q7E") { Ecount++; }

        var most = Math.max(Acount, Bcount, Ccount, Dcount, Ecount)
        if (most = Acount) { winner = As }
        if (most = Bcount) { winner = Bs }
        if (most = Ccount) { winner = Cs }
        if (most = Dcount) { winner = Ds }
        if (most = Ecount) { winner = Es }
    }
</script>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1. When you wake up in the morning you reach for _____.<br />
                <input value="Q1A" type="radio" name="amReach" />A. Your running shoes<br />
                <input value="Q1B" type="radio" name="amReach" />B. Your cellphone<br />
                <input value="Q1C" type="radio" name="amReach" />C. Your dog's leash<br />
                <input value="Q1D" type="radio" name="amReach" />D. What? I never slept.<br />
                <input value="Q1E" type="radio" name="amReach" />E. The newspaper<br />

            </td>
            <td>5. Which <em>How I Met Your Mother</em> character do you most relate to?<br />
                <input value="Q5A" type="radio" name="HIMYM" />A. I don't watch TV<br />
                <input value="Q5B" type="radio" name="HIMYM" />B. Robin<br />
                <input value="Q5C" type="radio" name="HIMYM" />C. Marshall and Lily<br />
                <input value="Q5D" type="radio" name="HIMYM" />D. Barney<br />
                <input value="Q5E" type="radio" name="HIMYM" />E. Ted<br />

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2. My preferred mode of transportation is _____.<br />
                <input value="Q2A" type="radio" name="transportation" />A. Bike<br />
                <input value="Q2B" type="radio" name="transportation" />B. Car<br />
                <input value="Q2C" type="radio" name="transportation" />C. Walking<br />
                <input value="Q2D" type="radio" name="transportation" />D. Limousine<br />
                <input value="Q2E" type="radio" name="transportation" />E. Rapid<br />

            </td>
            <td>6. The Miley Cyrus song that best represents my life is _____.<br />

                <input value="Q6A" type="radio" name="MileyCyrus" />A. "We Can't Stop"<br />
                <input value="Q6B" type="radio" name="MileyCyruS" />B. "The Climb"<br />
                <input value="Q6C" type="radio" name="MileyCyrus" />C. "The Best of Both Worlds"<br />
                <input value="Q6D" type="radio" name="MileyCyrus" />D. "Party in the U.S.A."<br />
                <input value="Q6E" type="radio" name="MileyCyrus" />E. "Wrecking Ball"<br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3. You can connect with me on _____.<br />
                <input value="Q3A" type="radio" name="SocialNetwork" />A. Foursquare<br />
                <input value="Q3B" type="radio" name="SocialNetwork" />B. LinkedIn<br />
                <input value="Q3C" type="radio" name="SocialNetwork" />C. Facebook<br />
                <input value="Q3D" type="radio" name="SocialNetwork" />D. Twitter<br />
                <input value="Q3E" type="radio" name="SocialNetwork" />E. Instagram<br />
            </td>
            <td>7. The weather forecaster I trust most is _____.<br />
                <input value="Q7A" type="radio" name="WeatherForecaster" />A. Angelica Campos<br />
                <input value="Q7B" type="radio" name="WeatherForecaster" />B. Mark Johnson<br />
                <input value="Q7C" type="radio" name="WeatherForecaster" />C. Betsy Kling<br />
                <input value="Q7D" type="radio" name="WeatherForecaster" />D. Jeff Tanchak<br />
                <input value="Q7E" type="radio" name="WeatherForecaster" />E. Dick Goddard<br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4. On a Friday night, you'll likely find me _____.<br />
                <input value="Q4A" type="radio" name="FridayNight" />A. Cheering at a sporting event<br />
                <input value="Q4B" type="radio" name="FridayNight" />B. Enjoying a great meal<br />
                <input value="Q4C" type="radio" name="FridayNight" />C. Curled up watching a movie<br />
                <input value="Q4D" type="radio" name="FridayNight" />D. Wherever the party is<br />
                <input value="Q4E" type="radio" name="FridayNight" />E. Listening to a lecture<br />
            </td>
            <td style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <input value="Submit" type="submit" onclick="checkTest()">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<br />
<hr />
<br />
<a id="results"></a>
<h3 style="color:#CC0000">Results:</h3>
<div style="padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; width: 750px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px">
    <div class="result" id="As">
        <!--<img src="/Media/MediaManager/A_Shoe.jpg" class="pic" alt="" /><br />
-->
        <div><span class="MostlyHeader">Mostly A's</span></div>
        <div><span class="header">ACTIVE ADVENTURER</span></div>
        <div>You're always on the go whether you're training for a marathon, pumping iron or cheering on the home team.</div>
        <p><span class="youLive">You live at:</span> Euclid Block Apartments, a hip, affordable East Fourth address close to The Q, Progressive Field and a gym.</p>
        <p><span class="number">1.</span><!--<img src="/Media/MediaManager/A_Shoe.jpg" style="float:right; alt="" />-->Gather your weekend chi with free yoga classes at the House of Blues. Leave your stress behind, but bring your own mat.</p>
        <p><span class="number">2.</span> Hop on your bike and cycle over to Good To Go Cafe on East Ninth for a quick smoothie.</p>
        <p><span class="number">3.</span><!--<img src="/Media/MediaManager/A_Shoe.jpg" style="float:right; alt="" />-->Swing by Hermes Cleveland to pick up your race packet for tomorrow's 5k.</p>
        <p><span class="number">4.</span> Down a protein-packed double decker rice and beans burger ($17) at Greenhouse Tavern.</p>
        <p><span class="number">5.</span><!--<img src="/Media/MediaManager/A_Shoe.jpg" style="float:right; alt="" />-->Score some pointers for your jump shot while watching Kyrie Irving and the rest of the Cavs at The Q.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's the actual problem with what you have?

Comment: What have you tried? It's better if you take some time to describe your attempts at the solution, and defining a specific problem.

Comment: You have errors in your code. For example: `if (most = Acount)` should be `if (most == Acount)...` etc.

Comment: My issue is that I'm counting the results from the quiz. Let's say, for example there are 6 "A"s clicked in the quiz, then the results (in the html below) will have a highlighted div to show that as the results. My issue is that I can count the questions and such, but don't know where to go from there as to changing the background.

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery you can manipulate the CSS-Properties of elements easily.

Changing the background color of an element would be called like this:

`$('[your element]').css('background','yellow');`

Exchange [your element] with an applicable CSS selector.

Also see here:

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Just in case: You must include the JQuery-library for this.